# How to install internet explorer and/or x86 emulator on raspbery pi 4b

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, windows

I have a rasbery pi 4b 8gb and I want to install internet explorer on it.  I am running ubuntu 21.10.  I tried installing internet explorer 8 with PlayOnLinux and the installing window says "error downlading POL_wine" and internet explorer does not work at all.  I made sure every wine package I could find was installed but still no success.  I heard (From a link sent to me by @seamus in the comments) that I may need an x86 emulator.  I looked around and I could not find any downloads of an emulator for the pi 4b; only the pi 3.  Does anyone know of such an emulator that is free and will work on a pi4?

Comment: This question does not appear to be specific to the Raspberry Pi within the scope defined in the [help center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This is an OS-specific issue with Ubuntu - you should [ask the question there](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: It does have to do with raspberry pi.  I have asked this on ask ubuntu but nobody knows much about arm processors.  I am looking for somebody who knows about a lot raspis and this (I think) is the place to find someone.

Comment: i don't believe wine covers emulating x86 on arm.  if i'm not wrong, wine just provides equivalent shared libs to the windows os so that when a .exe looks for windows dlls it finds those instead.  you'll have to run a full vm or at least somehow translate the original .exe from x86 to arm.

Comment: Do you know of such a vm???  If you could put that in answer form, It would be great.

Comment: If your issue is with `wine`, [maybe this will help](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=run+wine+on+raspberry+pi&atb=v278-1&ia=web).

Comment: That is very interesting, but all the tutorials are for raspberry pi 3.  None are for pi 4.

Comment: I have another image of raspi os that I play cube games on.  Emulation=faster than normal in my case.